# How do you export to a file in a Stored Proc?

Tags: t-sql

I tried BCP, but doesn't work.  Sql keeps giving me some Help text..

Anyway, it doesn't matter, as I don't want to paste the contents of the stored proc AGAIN into a string so this can export.

My Question:  **I have an existing stored proc. I would like it to automatically kick its result out into a text file.**

Any clues?

Comment: @KevinDeus - bcp throws help text when it's called incorrectly.  Can you paste in an example that doesn't work for you?  Maybe someone can fix the syntax for you.

Comment: I would, unfortunately my work firewall wont let it through! So i had to strip it out.

Are you saying that BCP is a good method to use for exporting in an existing stored proc? wouldn't you have to copy your stored proc text again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is very easy

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_AppendToFile(@FileName varchar(255), @Text1 varchar(255)) AS
DECLARE @FS int, @OLEResult int, @FileID int

EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @FS OUT
IF @OLEResult <> 0 PRINT 'Scripting.FileSystemObject'
:Open a file
execute @OLEResult = sp_OAMethod @FS, 'OpenTextFile', @FileID OUT, @FileName, 8, 1
IF @OLEResult <> 0 PRINT 'OpenTextFile'

--Write Text1
execute @OLEResult = sp_OAMethod @FileID, 'WriteLine', Null, @Text1
IF @OLEResult <> 0 PRINT 'WriteLine'

EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OADestroy @FileID
EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OADestroy @FS

from: http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_SQLWrFile/

Comment: This worked for me, but it only works a single field at a time. it would be better if there was a way to output an entire row or table at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have stored procedure MyProc in database MyDB on server MyServer, and you want results in tab delimited output file MyResults:

> bcp "exec MyDB.dbo.MyProc"  queryout MyResults -T -c -t\t -S MyServer

should work.  bcp offers a lot of other options for output as well.